# Scroller on CardView not working properly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have implemented cardview with recyclerview in my app. I have issue while scrolling the cardview records..When i scroll down and load more records then new records are replaced with old one and old records are not showing when scroll up.i don't want to replace the old records.

Code snip:

```
    recList.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            int firstVisiblesItems, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                if(dy > 0) //check for scroll down
                {
                    visibleItemCount = recList.getChildCount();
                    totalItemCount = llm.getItemCount();
                    firstVisiblesItems = llm.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                    final int lastItem = firstVisiblesItems + visibleItemCount;

                    if (lastItem == totalItemCount && totalItemCount != 0 && Restotcnt - lastItem >= totresults && stprocess == 1) {
//                            // you have reached end of list, load more data
                        totcount = lastItem + 1;
                        limit = limit + totresults;
                        new LoadContestList(getApplicationContext()).execute();
//                    Log.d("limit=", limit + "-results=-" + totresults);
                    }
                }


            }
        });
```

Here is my complete code for Async Class:

```
    public class LoadContestList extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        JSONArray contacts = null;
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        private Context context;
        ArrayList<contestInfo> arrayList = new ArrayList<contestInfo>();
        public LoadContestList(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            listofcontests.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            recList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivityz.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try{

                stprocess=0;
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
                jsonObj.put("limitCountMin", limit);
                jsonObj.put("totalResults", totresults);
                jsonObj.put("sort", "most-views");
                jsonObj.put("days", "");
                jsonObj.put("posted_search", ""); // Set the first name/pair
                jsonObj.put("rewardSearch", "");
                jsonObj.put("categories","");
                jsonObj.put("expiry", "");
                jsonObj.put("contestWorth", textSeek_text.getText().toString());
                jsonObj.put("MediaType","");
                jsonObj.put("ParticipationType",aParticipation);
                jsonObj.put("AgeType", aAge);
                jsonObj.put("TargetType", aTarget);
                jsonObj.put("TalentType", aTalent);
                jsonObj.put("RewardType", aReward);

                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                jsonArray.put(jsonObj);

                final HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(LOAD_CONTEST_LIST_URL);

                String str = jsonArray.toString().replace("[", "");
                String str1 = str.replace("]", "");

                httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(str1.toString()));
                HttpResponse resp = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity ent = resp.getEntity();

                String result = EntityUtils.toString(ent);
                JSONObject jsobj = new JSONObject(result);
                Res = jsobj.getString(TAG_RESULT);

                if (Res.equals("Success")) {
                    flag = true;
                    ResData = jsobj.getString(TAG_DATA);

                    if (!ResData.equals("No Result")) {

                        Restotcnt = jsobj.getInt(TAG_TOTAL_COUNT);
                        Rescntbusiness = jsobj.getInt(TAG_COUNT_BUSINESS);

                        JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsobj.getJSONArray("data");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray1.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(i);
                            contestInfo ci = new contestInfo();

                            ci.id = c.getString(TAG_CONTEST_ID);
                            ci.image = c.getString(TAG_CONTEST_IMAGE);
                            ci.name = c.getString(TAG_CONTEST_NAME);
                            ci.winStr = c.getString(TAG_WIN_STRING);
                            ci.description = c.getString(TAG_CONTEST_DESCR);
                            ci.date = c.getString(TAG_CONTEST_DATE);

                            arrayList.add(ci);
                        }
                        Log.d("CardArray",arrayList+"");


                    } else {
                        flag = false;

                    }
//                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
//                        @Override
//                        public void run() {
//                            contestcout.setText(Restotcnt.toString());
//                            brandcout.setText(Rescntbusiness.toString());
//                            contestListCustom adapter = new contestListCustom(MainActivityz.this, contestid, contestname, contestdescription, contestdateandtime, logo);
//                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//                            listofcontests.setAdapter(adapter);
//                            listofcontests.setSelection(limit);
//                            pDialog.dismiss();
//
//                        }
//                    });

                }

            }

            catch (JSONException ej)
            {
                flag = false;
                ej.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                flag = false;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }


        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            if(flag)
            {

                contestcout.setText(Restotcnt.toString());
                brandcout.setText(Rescntbusiness.toString());
                ContactAdapter ca = new ContactAdapter(MainActivityz.this,arrayList);
                ca.notifyDataSetChanged();
                recList.setAdapter(ca);

                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
            else
            {
//                flag =false;
//                listofcontests.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                nodatafound = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvInternetAlert);
//                nodatafound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        stprocess=1;
        }

    }
```

Please help me.

Comment: Send your complete code. Probably you are updating your adapter rather than adding item and notify your adapte.

Comment: i have edited my question @Uma Shankar

Comment: can anybody help me please?

Comment: please help me.. i am unable to do this

Comment: i understood but how can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

make global arrayList like

private List ca = new ArrayList<>();

Also make global instance of your adapter like

private ContactAdapter ca;

then inside your onCreate method add following these lines

ca = new ContactAdapter(MainActivityz.this,arrayList);
recList.setAdapter(ca);

now inside onPostExecute just write

notifyDataSetChanged();

your problem will be solved.
Let me know if still you face any issue

Comment: thanks a lot my dear!
you just saved my day and time
thanks once again

Comment: Accept my answer if it helps you